Python comparison dunder methods, implicit type casting
I'd like to use comparison dunder method, but I faced with issue with types casting.
Example: when I compare float with int usin < operator everything is fine.
But, when I use dunder method __lt__, it raises NotImplemented
In [19]: 123 < 150.6
Out[19]: True

In [20]: getattr(123, '__lt__')(150.6)
Out[20]: NotImplemented

What methods calls when I use 123 < 150.6? I supposed that python just call (123).__lt__(150.6), but it doesn't work. And I haven't find anything useful other than this in the documentation.

There is no type casting in python.

@quamrana of course there is type casting. float('123') is perfectly valid. I think you mean implicit type casting?

Quibble: the f in f'__lt__' is superfluous. No need to use f-strings when you don't interpolate anything. Also, (123).__lt__(150.6) would be more straight forward.

If the duplicates aren't clear enough: try (150.6).__gt__(123). That's what < falls back on when it encounters NotImplemented. The float type knows about integers, but not the other way around.

@deceze, ofc, f-string here was accidently added from a bit more complex code)
I'm aware that I can use comparison dunder method of float to compare with int, but, anyway, how construction 123 < 150.6 works? Does python converts it to 150.6 > 123 under hood?

@roganjosh: of course there is no type  casting in python.  Plenty of type conversion.

@quamrana they are synonymous according to Wikipedia

Again: < falls back on the reversed comparison, if it encounters NotImplemented. Also see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#richcmpfuncs.
